# Parsing the Log files in Python

Tags: python

I want to automate the manual analysis of the log file. The log file contains events data in the form of signals [raw text data]. Events are connection, media and .. For each of the events I know which which signals to see in the log file. My Idea is to add a configuration file for each of the event, this configuration file would contain the expected signals for that particular event.

Now when the issue is reported like connection not happening I would like parse the log file against this configuration file and would like to pop up missing signals for the event.

Please let me know which Python Library suits my requirement!
Thanks in advance..